# Need Salted MD5 technique for login

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, md5, saltedhash

I need the following methods for login module and reset-password module.

a) Salted MD5 technique in "authentication or login module‟

b) MD5 hash technique in "reset password‟ modules.

and how it should work, I write the description below.

When a client requests for the login page, the server should generates a random number, the salt, and sends it to the client along with the page. A JavaScript code on the client computes the MD5 hash of the password entered by the user. It then concatenates the salt to the hash and re-computes the MD5 hash. This result is then sent to the server. The server picks the hash of the password from its database, concatenates the salt and computes the MD5 hash. If the user entered the correct password these two hashes should match. The server compares the two and if they match, the user is authenticated.

Any reference any link which does the same.

Comment: If you are using HTTPS, you can simplify the client side logic, and just send the password over to the backend, where it will salt+hash it, and compare this to the value in the database.

Comment: Yes I am using HTTPS, but how to implement client side logic? and how to implement salted MD5 methods? any reference? This is the first time I am doing this so not much aware.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using HTTPS, you don't need to go through all the trouble of hashing + salting your password on the client side - you have HTTPS to handle the confidentiality of the password in transit between the client/server for you.

Simply send the password to the server. The server will be responsible for hashing + salting the password, and matching that value against what it has stored in the database.

For Salting + Hashing server side, I would recommend BCrypt:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt

You use it to generate a unique salt for each password stored. Also the hash algorithm itself is much slower than SHA1/MD5 (SHA1/MD5 are made for speed - not a useful property when storing passwords).

Comment: actually security audit of my web application being done. I never gone through this before. I used MD5 technique (but not salted MD5) in my code file not on the client side. But my auditor says -- "Implementing SSL is not the solution. Kindly implement proper salting technique so that the password is not passed in clear text." Now what to do? I have to implement this all as the auditor suggested.

Comment: Your question describes the process really well if you want to go that route. Heres a bcrypt implementation in js http://code.google.com/p/javascript-bcrypt/. You will need a bcrypt library for the backend as  well and you should be set.

Comment: Make sure you don't use md5. Any competent auditor will fail you for that.

Comment: But I am very new to use this. Could you please help me to implement this, what you suggested.